# Why do some paths in svg work and some do not

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to create svg blobs with images inside them. The first blob came out well, but the second doesn't work at all. Code is almost identical, you can see it below.

The one that was working

```
<img src="{{URL::asset('assets/images/homelanding.jpg')}}" alt="first" class="landing-clip">
        <svg>
            <clipPath id="landingClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">

                <path
                    d="M0.856,0.043 C0.922,0.081,0.96,0.153,0.98,0.223 C1,0.292,1,0.359,0.995,0.425 C0.986,0.492,0.964,0.557,0.918,0.61 C0.871,0.663,0.801,0.703,0.702,0.782 C0.603,0.861,0.476,0.979,0.345,0.997 C0.213,1,0.079,0.935,0.032,0.825 C-0.016,0.716,0.025,0.579,0.023,0.456 C0.021,0.335,-0.024,0.228,0.018,0.155 C0.059,0.081,0.186,0.042,0.298,0.021 C0.409,0.001,0.506,-0.001,0.601,0 C0.696,0.001,0.79,0.005,0.856,0.043"></path>

            </clipPath>
        </svg>
```

and the second one that is not working

```
<img src="{{URL::asset('assets/images/guru.jpg')}}" alt="first" class="guru-clip">
                    <svg>
                        <clipPath id="guruClip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                                <path d="M402.929 42.3239C452.578 64.0143 517.521 79.1976 544.445 117.481C571.262 155.656 559.954 217.04 536.583 269.639C513.213 322.347 477.672 366.379 433.623 396.962C389.575 427.545 337.018 444.681 302.877 419.195C268.844 393.6 253.228 325.167 203.579 296.427C153.93 267.687 70.1401 278.532 29.43 251.853C-11.1724 225.174 -8.80304 160.97 30.6147 130.495C70.0324 100.02 146.606 103.382 195.071 81.3666C243.535 59.2424 263.998 11.6319 291.461 1.97971C318.816 -7.67252 353.28 20.6335 402.929 42.3239Z"/>
                        </clipPath>
                    </svg>
```

There's also some scss going on, but it doesn't matter much here because it's almost the same as the first one.

```
.casestudy-blob {
    @include m.absolute(90%,15%);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    @include m.lightLeft;
    img {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
}
.guru-clip {
  clip-path: url("#guruClip");
}
```

I would be very thankful if somebody told me what's the problem with second blob. Only difference between the first one and the second one is the path. Blob copied as SVG from Figma.

Comment: object bounding box units are 0..1 the first path has values in that range, the second has numbers that are far too big.

Comment: hm, okay. Thanks for that. Any ideas on how to export it from Figma then? @RobertLongson

Comment: Figured out that I can resize it to 1px width and then export. Kinda bad solution but it works.

Comment: If somebody will need to convert SVG to relative clip-path, then this would help you out https://yoksel.github.io/relative-clip-path/